# Picking breeders in a genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm implementing a genetic algorithm, and I'm uncertain on how to pick the breeders for the next generation:

I am holding a list of all the past individuals calculated,

Is it ok if I select the breeders from this list? or should I rather pick the best ones from the latest generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only select from the latest generation, it's possible for your population to evolve backwards.  There's no guarantee that later generations are better than earlier ones.  To prevent this, some algorithms maintain a pool of "elite" individuals that continually mix with the regular population.  (The strategy is called "elitism".)  A particularly successful version of this approach is Coello's micro-GA, which uses a very small population with elite preservation and frequent restarts to make progress.

Comment: Here's the citation:

Coello Coello Coello C.A., Toscano Pulido G. (2001) A Micro-Genetic Algorithm for Multiobjective Optimization. In: Zitzler E., Thiele L., Deb K., Coello Coello C.A., Corne D. (eds) Evolutionary Multi-Criterion Optimization. EMO 2001. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 1993. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg

Comment: Thanks, my target function computation is quite expensive, while my results are light, so I'm keeping a `population_history` dictionary (identified by a hash), so I have all the previous results available, I changed my breeders selection to include also a few of the best "alltimers" and I think this improved my results. I'm undecided whether to include a random sample of the "alltimers" as well, or maybe generate some "brand new" individuals, just to add genes variety. for now I'm satisfied with this heuristics, I'm good for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's *usually* preferable to select the ones that have the **highest fitness value**

- Based on a certain function that you define, evaluate individuals in your population and choose the best *N* ones. For example, the *lightest* rocks in algorithm where you want to generate light rocks.
- **If computing** the fitness value of **all** individuals in your population is **costly** operations, you should first select a **sample** based on some distribution. A good one is to select in a *uniform* fashion (all individuals have equal probabilities to be selected)
- If you can't easily define a fitness function, a good technique is to run simulations. For example if your *phenotype* (criteria) is hard to define, like a shape of an irregular 3D object for example.

Comment: that would be the highest fitness value among the latest population or all the individuals ever generated?

Comment: Latest population

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following methods to select breeders( parent)
 - Roulette wheel selection 
 - Stochastic Universal Sampling
 - Tournament Selection
 - Random Selection

Reference : 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/genetic_algorithms/genetic_algorithms_parent_selection.htm

Comment: Thanks, but hardly any of these strategies mention whether to pick your breeder from the latest population generated or from all the individuals ever generated, in my implementation I've  tried both options, and my feeling is that if I use the total population the algo converges pretty quickly to a local optimum, while if you pick the latest population only, you somehow get more diversity, and converge slower, but to a generally better solution. I'm considering whether would be a good idea to include a mix of both.